# settimeout() interval is speed is changing by clicking a start button

Tags: javascript

actually start button is changing image but when i click again start button the speed of animation change javascript

```
function start() {
  SlideId = setInterval(change, 1000);
}

function change() {
  var rotator = document.getElementById("rotator");
  if (current == "1") {
    rotator.src = "http://nwp.imd.gov.in/wrf/WRFd01-MSLP_00.png";
    current = "2";
  } else if (current == "2") {
    rotator.src = "http://nwp.imd.gov.in/wrf/WRFd01-MSLP_24.png";
    current = "3";
  } else if (current == "3") {
    rotator.src = "http://nwp.imd.gov.in/wrf/WRFd01-MSLP_48.png";
    current = "4";
  } else if (current == "4") {
    rotator.src = "http://nwp.imd.gov.in/wrf/WRFd01-MSLP_72.png";
    current = "5";
  } else {
    rotator.src = "http://nwp.imd.gov.in/wrf/WRFd01-MSLP_00.png";
    current = "1";
  }
}
```

i want that when i again press the start button the speed of image duration must be same

Comment: because you are executing multiple `setInetvals ` at ones

Comment: actually the functinality is good but a problem is that i have 2 button - start and stop .    When i click the 2 time start button the speed change of image duration automatically

Comment: @GauravGarg the statement @Dadboz provided still holds: when you click the button invoking `start()` twice without invalidating the interval, each of these will fire continuously at the proper intervals until they are invalidated.

Comment: bhai after adding this start button stop working. bhai code yeah hai isme change karna hai      view-source:http://nwp.imd.gov.in/animatewrf27.php

Answer (score 2):

If you don't stop an `interval` function it's not gonna stop from it self ... so doing more clicks (`start()`) will generate more `ìntervals` and for that you will have to stop the previous interval and start new one :

```
function start() {
   clearInterval(SlideId) 
   SildeId = setInterval(change, 1000);
}
```

Comment: bhai after adding this start button stop working. bhai code yeah hai isme change karna hai                                                                                                                              
             view-source:http://nwp.imd.gov.in/animatewrf27.php

Comment: bhai please is link ko kholna and check karke btao bahi kaisa thik karu yeah bug

Comment: @GauravGarg sorry i don't understand indian

Comment: actually i want that please open the link in the browser as well suspect the code of animation you will able to see the bug which i am telling to you of start button when you press 2 or more time      view-source:http://nwp.imd.gov.in/animatewrf27.php

Comment: @GauravGarg you have to stop the previous interval on all the functions before starting a new one

Answer (score 2):

Just add `clearInterval(SlideId);` as the first line in your function.

Comment: bhai after adding this start button stop working. bhai code yeah hai isme change karna hai      view-source:http://nwp.imd.gov.in/animatewrf27.php